# Windows Update error 80070003

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

I am getting this error while running Windows Update for following updates

> Update for Microsoft Excel 2013 (KB2752087) 32-Bit Edition

I have already tried solution at [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-error-80070003#1TC=windows-7)

**Config:**

- Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 32bit Build 7601
- MS Office 2013

Comment: What is your OS, version number, bitiness, and what M$ office package did you install.

Comment: @mdpc See added info

Comment: Did you try http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910336

Comment: @DaveRook Yes it helped and problem has been fixed. Post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a KB for this, which may resolve it for you

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910336

> Windows Update error "0x80070002" or "0x80070003"
>
> This troubleshooter: "Automatically diagnose and fix common problems with Windows Update" may automatically fix your problem.
>
> This troubleshooter fixes many different problems.