# Issue Installing Windows 10

Tags: windows

In order to download the windows 10 update I need to update my win7 files. Due to a problem my updates are failing, thus not letting me update to win10. Problem Code 80070003. I tried deleting the files from DataStore but some txt files are being used by Application Information and Application Experience. What can I do?

Comment: So doesn't this community also solve general software issues? And for me being a new one that doesn't know this you downvote my question? Thank you very much Sir.

Comment: This community (Super User) isnt about only programming issues PeeHaa.. You are probably confused with StackOverflow

Comment: @Master-Guy, you're confused; PeeHaa commented *before* the question was migrated here...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Update error 80070003](http://superuser.com/questions/752363/windows-update-error-80070003)

Answer (score 0):

Stop *Windows Update* service
delete everything from the following locations:-
C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\EventCache
C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download
C:\Windows\Temp
C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore

Run the update again and you will be good to go!

Comment: That doesn't work for the KB3035490 and KB3023224 problem.  See the thread on Microsoft Support.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. With me it was because of the hardware in my computer. Two possible solutions:

1) Turn off your PC, unplug all USB devices (except your keyboard and mouse), disconnect all secondary hard-drives, and boot your system again. Then download and upgrade.

2) Do a clean install of your current OS, then do the upgrade again. With no drivers installed for your hardware, the update will also proceed normally.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Microsoft Fix-It which will perform an automated reset of your Windows Update configuration.

This succeeded for me where all other tricks had failed.  Including running the Windows Update Readiness Tool, running `sfc /scannow` and clearing the software distribution folder.

Look for **Microsoft Fix It 50202** in your favourite search engine.

[image: Fix it 50202 Screenshot]

Try running it without the *Aggressive* option first.  Although for me, the problem was only solved after I did use the *Aggressive* option.